# How to enable navigating Laravel definitions in PhpStorm?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

When I am pressing `Ctrl-B` on association between root and function, it shows me

[image]

> Cannot find declaration to go.

How to fix?

Comment: Such Laravel-specific navigation is provided by Laravel plugin. Install corresponding plugin.

Comment: P.S. Try using this one instead: `[AuthController::class, 'login']` -- such syntax/navigation is handled by PhpStorm itself.

Answer (score 1):

its not that easy, mostly because of the magic under the hood of laravel.

To solve your problem ill recommend you a few tools:

1. https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper - Free package which will generate a lot of annotations which allows you to easy navigate between files.
2. https://laravel-idea.com/ - Paid plugin with a trial, simplifies a lot of operations.
3. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7532-laravel - Free to use, also provides nice features out of the box